# CSS selector for several id's within a parent class

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a way to target several different id's within a parent class with a css selector.

I am aware that its not common to do this since id's need to be unique in order to validate, and thus there is limited practical use for such a solution. I was initially intending to use this code for a school project. I've since found a valid workaround but I still wonder if this can be done, and if so how.

```
           <form class="example6">
                <div>
                    <h3>Contact form</h3>
                    <label>
                        <span>Your name</span><input  id="name" type="text" name="name" />
                    </label>

                    <label>
                        <span>Email Address</span><input id="email" type="text" name="email" />
                    </label>

                    <label>
                        <span>Subject</span><input  id="subject" type="text" name="subject" />
                    </label>

                    <label>
                        <span>Message</span><textarea  name="feedback"></textarea>

                    </label>
                 </div>
             </form>
```

I want to select #name, #email and #subject, but only if within .example6.

Comment: And where are you stuck: `.example6 #name` (etc...) didn't work?

Answer (score 2):

A [descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors) is a way to select only children of the ancestor / parent (`parent child`) whether they are elements,  classes, IDs etc. The selection is denoted by the space between selectors

```
.example6 #name {

}
```

You can comma separate for multiple selectors and apply the same CSS

```
.example6 #name, .example6 #email, .example6 #subject {

}
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BrianDillingham/qbyv12u6/)

Comment: In the (potentially overly-simplified) code in the question there's also the possibility of a more concise selector: `.example6 input[id] {…}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
.example6 > div > label > input{
    border-color: red;
}
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/b4uovhac/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.example6 #name, .example6 #email, .example6 #subject {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.

You can comma separate multiple expresions:

```
.example6 #name, .example6 #email, .example6 #subject {...}
```

or find something else that's unique to the element (eg: they are the only `inputs` within `.example6`)

```
.example6 input{...}
```

or use attribute selectors to get just the inputs having type=text:

```
.example6 input[type=text]{...}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/au0drh1w/